# Compiler Error C2440 in C

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, double

I'm finishing a program that I found in my C book but I ran into some issues.
I'm just about done but I keep getting this error
Error   1   error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from 'double [15]' to '
Why am i getting this compiler error?

```
void arrayRead(double, int*);

void arrayList(double, int*);

void arraySum(double, int*, int*);

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    int num, sum = 0;
    double array[15];
    printf("How many doubles (numbers) would you like in the array (20 max)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Thank you! Now give me %d different doubles (numbers) please!\n", num);

    arrayRead(array, &num);

    printf("Here are all of your integers again!\n");

    arrayList(array, &num);

    arraySum(array, &num, &sum);
    printf("The sum of these numbers = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}

void arrayRead(double array[], int* num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &array);
    }
}

void arrayList(double array[], int*num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *num; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f\n", array);
    }
}

void arraySum(double array[], int*num, int* sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *num; i++)
    {
        *sum = array + *sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void arrayRead(double, int*);` --> `void arrayRead(double*, int*);` ditto.

Comment: your array function prototypes don't match your array function definitions

Comment: Also `scanf("%lf", &array);` --> `scanf("%lf", &array[i]);`

Comment: The easiest (and I would say the best) way to create a function prototype is to copy the function definition, paste it, and tack a semicolon on the end. On the other hand, if you put `main` at the bottom of the file, then you don't even need the function prototypes.

Comment: these lines conflict (15 .vs. 20)  `double array[15];
    printf("How many doubles (numbers) would you like in the array (20 max)?\n");`   suggest moving the declaration for `array[]` to after the call to `scanf()`  similar to: `unsigned num;  ... printf("How many doubles (numbers) would you like in the array ?\n"); scanf("%u", &num);  double array[ num ];`   Of course, the code should also be checking the returned value (not the parameter value) from `scanf()` AND checking that it is a reasonable value, say in the range 1...20.

Comment: the prototype for arrayRead() is currently: `void arrayRead(double, int*);` but it needs to be: `void arrayRead(double*, int*);`    Notice that the first parameter is also a pointer.  Similar considerations need to be applied to the prototypes for: `arrayList()` and `arraySum()`.

Comment: Now i have no more C2440 errors let see if i can finish the program

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `scanf("%lf", &array);` the code needs to access individual elements, not the whole array.  suggest: `scanf("%lf", &array[i]);`  Similar considerations need to be applied to the calculation of the `sum` in the `arraySum()` function.

Comment: @user3629249 For some reason my array list brings back the value 0 to the users

Comment: @user3386109   For some reason my array list brings back the value 0 to the users

Answer (score 0):

best to place prototypes after any #include statements,
just in case the prototype uses something defined in the header file

The size of the array must be a positive number,
so use '%u' to input a positive numbe
and define the `max` variable as unsigned

The parameters to functions and the parameters passed when calling those functions need to have matching types (or the function type be a 'promotion' of the passed type.

since the array is `doubles`, all the references should also be `double`, like the `sum` variable.

appropriate horizontal white space makes the code much easier to read

do not #include header files those contents are not being used.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <ctype.h>

// prototypes
void arrayRead( double*, unsigned );
void arrayList( double*, unsigned );
void arraySum ( double*, unsigned, double* );

int main( void )
{
    unsigned num;
    double sum = 0.0;

    printf( "How many doubles (numbers) would you like in the array (20 max)?\n" );
    if( 1 != scanf( "%u", &num ) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for size of array failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    // need to add check that user entered value is in range 1...20

    double array[ num ];

    printf( "Thank you! Now give me %u different doubles (numbers) please!\n", num );
    arrayRead( array, num );

    printf( "Here are all of your integers again!\n" );
    arrayList( array, num );

    arraySum( array, num, &sum );
    printf("The sum of these numbers = %lf\n", sum);
    return 0;
} // end function: main


void arrayRead( double array[], unsigned num )
{
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        scanf("%lf", &array[i]);
    }
} // end function: arrayRead


void arrayList( double array[], unsigned num )
{
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        printf("%.2f\n", array[i]);
    }
} // end function: arrayList


void arraySum( double array[], unsigned num, double* sum )
{
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        *sum = array[i] + *sum;
    }
} // end function: arraySum
```

Here is the output from a simple run of the answer code:

```
How many doubles (numbers) would you like in the array (20 max)?
5
Thank you! Now give me 5 different doubles (numbers) please!
1 1 1 1 1
Here are all of your integers again!
1.00
1.00
1.00
1.00
1.00
The sum of these numbers = 5.000000
```

Comment: Work the code over using your structure and the code doesn't add up all the numbers in the array

Comment: void arraySum(double array[], unsigned* num, double* sum)
{
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < *num; i++)
 {
  *sum = array[i] + *sum;
 }
}

Comment: If i take the * from unsigned and num the program doesn't run correctly

Comment: I changed all functions and prototypes to yours

Comment: @MoscaMentality,  The answer, as written, works correctly,  You can not (easily) pick and choose as to which parts to duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The functions you have declared have different signatures than the functions you have defined.

Be careful in the declaration you use `double` instead of `double *`. It is not the same.

When you call the `arrayRead` function and company, the compiler sees only the declared functions as the defined functions are after the calls. So the parameters doesn't match.

By the way, in the defined functions you forgot to write the index. You are using the pointer and this can't work. You need to write `array[i]` inside each loop.